# F# how to add type to list?

Tags: f#

So I am trying to create a card game for school project with F#. I am coming from C# and having problems in understanding stuff in F#. I have type

`Player = {Name : String; Hand : Card list}` which represents the player

then I have deck which has cards inside. How can I move the first card from the deck to players hand? In C# I would be using something like `removeat[i]`.

Comment: F# lists are immutable so you wouldn't remove an item, you would return something like a pair `(Player, Card list)` containing the player along with the remaining cards. Can you add an example of the function you're trying to write to populate the players?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
let returnFirstElement list =
  match list with
  | h::t -> Some(h),t
  | [] -> None,[]
```

Pass your list into this and it will return a tuple. The first value will be your card, the second is the rest of the deck.
The use of Some and None is there as if you run out of cards in your deck then you will not get a card back. 
As you are from a C# background think of `Some` as a nullable type and `None` as null. Look into F# `Some` and `None` if you are unsure it is pretty common to use them.

You can use this like

```
 let (topCard, restOfDeck) = returnFirstElement deckOfCards
```

Can give you more assistance if needed but that should be a good enough start.

Comment: Thanks this was exactly what I was looking for. I can now get the card with: let (topCard, deck) = playCard deck 
And this does what it should be, removes one card from deck etc. 
Now all that is left is how can I put that topCard to the players hand? List.append expects another list.

Comment: In addition to previous I am getting now "Number option" from that function even though the hand is "Number list". Creating a new list from the card with "let testlist = [card]" makes it "Number option list".

Comment: Hi @Kamsiinov, the issue you are having is that an Number Option is not a Number. As I said in my answer it is effectively a nullable Number, you have to handle both options. ```Some Number``` and ```None```.
I suggest you read this, so you understand how to handle the ```option```
https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/the-option-type/

Comment: Yes, I understood it bit later when I understood what the option is.

Answer (score 2):

To write idiomatic functional code in F#, you need to think about how to model the state of the system explicitly.  Each player has a hand of cards which represents part of the state but we also need to model the state of the deck as well.

Logically, drawing from the deck affects both the player's hand and the deck itself.

We also need to consider the error case when there are no cards in the deck.

Here is a simple example that simply errors when there are no cards left in the deck.

```
type Player = {Name : string; Hand : Card list}

let draw player deck =
    match deck with
    |[] -> invalidArg "deck" "No cards in deck!"
    |drawn::rest -> ({ player with Hand = drawn :: player.Hand }, rest)
```

You supply a `Player` and a deck represented by a `Card list` to the draw function and it returns you a new `Player` with a card taken from the deck and a new `Card list` without the card that was drawn.

For some games, you might be better having two lists of cards, one to draw from, one of discards.  Then, when you run out of cards, you could create a new deck by shuffling the discards.

Answer (score -1):

You can certainly use anything .Net in F# as well. This is not idiomatic F# but then again, it's debatable how much recursion is. Essentially if you want to remove an element from an F# list, maybe an F# list is not the best collection to be used. You can of course apply `filter` to it any time. But If all your items are unique, consider using a set.

Here's a version with .RemoveAt:

```
open System.Collections.Generic
let xs = ResizeArray [1;2;3]
xs.RemoveAt(2)

xs
```

ResizeArray is the synonym for C# List.

Regarding just moving the first card and taking the rest you can use 'tail' and 'head' functions.